# Search and replace certain keyword of nested list string in Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, replace, str-replace, nested-lists

#### Example:

`a=[['I am boy'],['she is girl'],['They both love each other']]
b={'boy':'Rohan','girl':'Pooja','love':'hate'}`

#### Desired output:

`a=[['I am Rohan'],['she is Pooja'],['They both hate each other']]`

MyCode:

`for i in a:
    print (i)
    for j in i:
        for k in b:
            if ((k in j)== True):
                j=j.replace(k,b[k])
                print (j)`

#### My Output:

`I am Rohan
she is Pooja
They both hate each other`

```

#### My doubt:

I am unable to get the output in desired format. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a minor update to your code.

```
temp_a = []
for i in a:
    print (i)
    for j in i:
        for k in b:
            if ((k in j)== True):
                j=j.replace(k,b[k])
                temp_a.append([j])
a = temp_a
```